# Como pasar un string hacia varios view controllers?

Tags: swift, swift4

Quiero pasar información obtenida de un textfield a varios view controllers, es posible? como?

gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Simplemente agrega una variable a los viewController, los inicializas y asignas el nuevo valo

Comment: usa NSNotificationCenter, te dejo este enlace que puede ayudarte. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar de un view controller a otro puedes relacionarlos mediante un segue way, de esta manera puedes pasar información de un view controller a otro.

Digamos que tienes un MyViewController1 y quieres pasar información a MyViewController2

class MyViewController1: UIViewController {

```
var infoPrueba: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Asignamos algún valor a la variable que deseamos
    infoPrueba = "Esta es una info"
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        //Obtenemos la referencia del siguiente view controller
        let controller2 = segue.destination as! MyViewController2
        //Aqui pasas la variable de información al siguiente view controller
        controller2.infoDeViewController1 = infoPrueba
    }
}
```

}

class MyViewController2: UIViewController {

```
var infoDeViewController1: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     //En este punto la variable debe contener la información del 
     anterior view controller
     print(infoDeViewController1)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas de compartir información en diferentes controladores, cuál utilices dependerá de que necesites. Las opciones más comunes son:

1. Por un segue(descrita anteriormente)
2. Crear una clase global

   ```
   class Global {
   static let sharedInstance = Global()

   var anyVariable: String
   }
   ```

En cualquier clase accedes al valor: 
        Global.sharedInstance.anyVariable

3. Por NotificationCenter (Especial cuidado), este método se utiliza en particular para enviar notificaciones desde una clase, y que estas sean recibidas por otra cualquiera que quiera suscribirse a la misma. los datos pueden enviarse dentro del objeto **userInfo** de la notificación

   ```
   Clase A Emitirá la notificación
   let nc = NotificationCenter.default
   nc.post(name:Notification.Name(rawValue:"Cambiounvalor"),object: nil, userInfo: ["valor":1])

   Clase B Recibirá la notificación
   let myNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue: "Cambiounvalor")
   let nc = NotificationCenter.default
   nc.addObserver(forName:myNotification, object:nil, queue:nil, using:metodoqueseejecuta)

   func metodoqueseejecuta(notification:Notification) -> Void {
   guard let index = notification.userInfo?["valor"] as? Int
   }
   ```
4. Delegados y Protocolos